# Matlab or ImageJ or Fiji image stitching

Tags: image, matlab, imagej

Looking for help in solving this problem. I understand how stitching works on Matlab and Fiji but what I have is a very particular case. I want to stich an series of images together. So the easiest way to describe it is lets say I am walking down a long street with a repeating pattern of buildings on both sides. So I snap a picture facing down the street which makes the buildings kind of in the Peripheral view. So I move a set number of steps and take another picture and so on and so forth. How would I stich these photos together using Fiji or Matlab.

Comment: Are you trying to stitch the image inside and shrunk from the image you took "a few steps back"? Am I understanding that correctly? Could you perhaps add an example using just two images, perhaps with a "stitched" image that is a mockup made in powerpoint or something?

Comment: This is not really a programming question. Maybe a photography forum would be better suited for this problem. Since you are moving your camera between two shots, you need to correct for spherical lens aberrations in the image periphery before stitching. You can also try the [scan workflow](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/tutorials/scans/en.shtml) of the Hugin tools.

Comment: An here is a sample of the images I am trying to stich [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bj1is442kseqswg/SUM_31.jpg?dl=0) [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3dgl4slklfxl6ur/SUM_33.jpg?dl=0)  thanks if you think the photography forum can help that I ask them as well. This is not a camera shot is the reading from a photon detector tile that is perpendicular to my emitter